# why using int64_t gives wrong result while double works as expected for simple integer multiplications

Tags: c++, int, double, factorial

here is my code :

```
using integer = int64_t;

integer factorial(integer number) {
    return number <= 0 ? 1 : number * factorial(number - 1);
}

integer binomial_coefficent(integer n, integer r) {
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n - r));
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << binomial_coefficent(40, 20) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this prints

```
0
```

which is wrong answer but if i change integer type to double that will print `1.37847e+11`
which is the correct answer,my question is why using int64_t gives me incorrect answer

Comment: i know integer(int64_t) can't represent fraction but i can't able to understand why int64_t gives me wrong result as 40! and 20!*20! will divide eachother

Comment: "int64_t doesn't overflow either" vs "int64_t giving wrong result" in the title.. you have two cases with two different outcomes, but I find it confusing in which case you are surprised by which outcome

Comment: `!40` is certainly going to overflow `int64_t` even if the final result wouldn't. Your data type has to be able to represent your intermediate terms, not just the result.

Comment: `40!` doesn't even fit in 128 bits!

Comment: Looks like you need to change algo to at least calculate P[max(n-r,r),n]/P[1,min(n-r,r)]

Comment: I can recommend [this](https://dmitrybrant.com/2008/04/29/binomial-coefficients-stirling-numbers-csharp) article.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> and int64_t doesn't overflow either

It does though. For debugging things like this, you can run this with `-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow` (implied by `-fsanitize=undefined`) in GCC or clang to see:

> runtime error: signed integer overflow: 21 * 2432902008176640000 cannot be represented in type 'long'
>   runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2432902008176640000 * 2432902008176640000 cannot be represented in type 'long'

Answer (score 5):

`40!` is about `8e47`. A 64 bit signed integer could hold at max `2^63-1`, about `1e19`.

`factorial(40)` does overflow, and since overflow of signed integer types is undefined behavior, anything you observe could not be explained.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome in the world of finite precision numbers! fact(40) is 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000 or 0x8eeae81b84c7f27e080fde64ff05254000000000 which will obviously not fit even in a `uint64_t` neither in a 128 bits `long long` since it actually requires 160 bits!

But the binomial coefficient 40, 20 can indeed be computed using `uint64_t` provided you use the correct algorithm that human beings were used to before computers come everywhere around:

```
integer binomial_coefficient(integer n, integer r) {
    integer bc = 1;
    integer q = n - r;
    for(integer i=1; i<=r; i++) {
        br = br * (q + i) / i;
    }
    return bc;
}
```

This one will give you the correct value of 137846528820 with no overflow.

(above function omits the test for r <= n/2 that can be an additional optimisation because Cn,p is by construction Cn,n-p)